# How to exclude contributed modules from being upgraded when we run composer install or composer update?

Tags: 8, ubercart, composer

I want to exclude contributed module Ubercart from being upgraded when we run composer install or composer update ? What change should I add in the composer.json so that it ignores ubercart contributed module ?
Seems to be simple question, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: What's in your `composer.json` for the line starting by : `"drupal/ubercart":` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In composer.json, you remove the `^` and specify the version

Ex: Normally most modules are like this:

```
"require": {
    "drupal/commerce: "^2.21",
},
```

and to lock it, you change to

```
"require": {
    "drupal/commerce: "2.20", // will always install version 2.20 and never update.
},
```

But because Ubercart is in Alpha, you'll see its currently

```
"require": {
    "drupal/ubercart: "^4.0@alpha",
},
```

And to lock needs to be

```
"require": {
    "drupal/ubercart": "4.0-alpha3", // will always install alpha 3 and never update.
},
```